# English translation of Even HaEzer

Tags: translation, shulchan-aruch, even-haezer

I need to do some research relating to Jewish women and read Joseph Caro’s Shulchan Aruch. It is really difficult for me to read Hebrew. Does Even HaEzer have an English translation? Or are there any English commentaries including it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An English translation of Even Ha'Ezer is available on Sefaria [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.1.1?lang=bi).

Comment: I want to find a book that translated by rabbi.

Comment: @Wong translateb by whom?

Comment: I mean, translated by whom?

Comment: What does Even Haezer mean?

Comment: @yishairasowsky Even Ha'ezer is the English transliteration of אבן העזר, which, in this context, is one of the four parts of the Shulchan Aruch. Literally, it means "the stone of help". See a little more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_Ha%27ezer.

Comment: thank you @Harel13! I actually meant to ask what it signifies. For example, I know that Choshen Misphat is probably called that name because it is relating with dinei torah beteen parties that needs judgment, like the Choshen would do. Or Orach Chayim is the laws of daily living. But Even Haezer and Yoreh Deah I don't really understand why they are called that. Does the Tur write an explanation at the preface of his work?

Comment: By any of rabbis of Judaism

Comment: Safaria do not have all translation, so I need a printed book

Comment: @Wong can you write what parts aren't translated? Because as far as I can tell, all of it has been translated.

Comment: For example, Orach Chayim siman 159: 4-10 and 13-20. I forgot other parts, sorry.

Comment: @Wong but you didn't ask in your question for Orach Chaim. You asked for Even Haezer. Those are two different parts of the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @Wong - the Shulchan Aruch is made up of four sections (Orach, Chaim, Even HaEzer, Choshen Mishpat and Yoreh Deah). Your question is currently asking for translation just on the section of Even HaEzer. Following on from you comment above, it would seem you are looking for more than just the Even HaEzer section. Perhaps refine your question to ask if you require the whole shulchan aruch or other sections?

Comment: I know. I just forgot the parts in Even HaEzer. So I mentioned Orach Chaim to show that there are seifim in Shulchan Aurch which have not translated yet. Sorry again. I am reading Even HaEzer again now.

Comment: @Wong Oh, okay. Good luck!

Comment: Even HaEzer siman1-3. These parts aren’t translated on Sefaria.

Comment: When I read again via VPN, they have English translations. It shocked me

Answer (score 1):

There's a partial or in-progress work at

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch/Even_ha-Ezer

Looks like roughly Siman 1 to 31 are complete as of now (Feb. 2022.)